# IPython | Unix commands not working in script but working in command line interpreter

Tags: ipython

Below lines when i put them in test.py and runs it, gives me error  but runs fine when i run them from command line.

```
pyvar = 'Hello world'
!echo "A python variable: {pyvar}"

jitu@jitu-PC:~/ipython/python$ ipython test.py 
 File "/home/jitu/ipython/python/test.py", line 2
 !echo "A python variable: {pyvar}"
 ^
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any idea  why it is not working ?

Comment: Rename your script to .ipy

Comment: @Matt maybe your comment could be an answer, with more explanation?

Comment: Yes, done, was hard to write answer from my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.py` file are python script, they are supposed to be pure python, IPython will not try to do some "magic" on it. You should rename your script to `.ipy` if you want to use the syntactic sugar IPython offers on top of pure python syntax.

Note that all IPython syntactic sugar can be transformed into pure python (cf `%hist` vs `%hist -t`) that will be valid python syntax, but still need to have access to an IPython instance.